# What are some tools & methods to create a photo contest on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Looking for ways to create a photo contest on Facebook beyond the ordinary Likes & Comments.

Are there any fancy specialized apps for this?

Free or low price preferred.

Comment: sample contest created http://www.facebook.com/pages/Olympics-Community/144166859031324?sk=app_256492287754458

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Facebook Contest Applications](http://www.votigo.com/corp/solutions/fbcontests.php)

Also read, [It’s a Violation To Run a Contest on Facebook](http://www.silversquareinc.com/blog/2010/06/its-a-violation-to-run-a-contest-on-facebook/)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Photo [Contest app by SocialAppsHQ](https://www.socialappshq.com/products/contest_tab-for-facebook-pages).

All FB regulations are taken care of in this case. You can also get started within 30 seconds!

Comment: Please can you make it clear that this is your site you are suggesting. If it's not 100% clear and 100% relevant to the question your answer will get deleted as spam.

Answer (score -1):

you can use our solution/on-line service for creating Facebook photo contest: http://www.facebook.com/pages/EazyContest-Test-Page/194762017220686?sk=app_219286784773055